# ASP.NET MVC: Calling a web service located in the same project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application. In the same project, there is an asmx web service. I'm being asked to create a new page whereby I have buttons that call the web service. The web service calls a stored procedure that deletes data from one of the tables. This stored procedure is located in the same database that the application is connected to.

My initial solution would be to simply bypass the web service call and simply call the stored procedure since it exists in the DMBL file and I can reference it using the data context.

But I'm being told to make sure the button calls the web service instead. I find this to be more complicated and poorer performance. My way has better performance and easier to implement.

Which way would any of you do this if you had the choice?

Comment: Based only on the information you gave, I agree with you.
However there may be a lot of reason to call web service instead. Have you asked to these person WHY use Web service? To test it, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a reference to the web service in the project. Usually you have to add this, but since the web service is located in the same project you might be able to skip adding the reference.

Once you have the web service reference, this is how you can call it:

```
protected void ConvertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    localhost.Convert wsConvert = new localhost.Convert();
    double temperature =
        System.Convert.ToDouble(TemperatureTextbox.Text);
    FahrenheitLabel.Text = "Fahrenheit To Celsius = " +
        wsConvert.FahrenheitToCelsius(temperature).ToString();
    CelsiusLabel.Text = "Celsius To Fahrenheit = " +
        wsConvert.CelsiusToFahrenheit(temperature).ToString();
}
```

Happy coding.